# esto es lo que me sale cuando ejecuto npm start, en el terminal de visual studio code, realmente ya no se que hacer, para solucionarlo

Tags: webpack

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: deacargue webpack-dev-server, en le package.json en la parte de los scritp coloque esto: "start": "webpack serve --open ", pero cuando ejecuto npm start me sale eso]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]png

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Sin ver tu codigo o saber algo mas dificil ayudarte... que fue lo que hiciste????

Comment: hola disculpa soy nuevo en esto, pero ya formule bien la pregunta, para que la vean y me den posibles soluciones

Comment: Eso dice que hay un error.. pero sin ver tu codigo, imposible saber donde esta el error... es muy probable que este en la linea anterior a la marcada...